# How to get the value of custom product attribute in order item

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

I am able to get the values of custom product attribute in the cart and checkout page.
Using the code below

```
<group name="quote_item">
    <attribute name="ts_dimensions_height"/>
    <attribute name="ts_dimensions_length"/>
    <attribute name="ts_dimensions_width"/>
</group>
```

In this file `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/catalog_attributes.xml`

I wanted to get the custom product attribute value from the ordered item after the order placed event.

Comment: create event  sales_order_place_after

Comment: @RkRathod I have created an event. I am able to get the order items data. I wanted to include the above-mentioned attribute in order item data

Comment: pleace attach code...

Comment: $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $orderItems = $order->getItems();
    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        $item->getData();
        //$item data doesn't have the ts_dimensions_height, ts_dimensions_length, ts_dimensions_width attribute values
    }